# where can i read about how cv2.findcontour work?

Tags: image, computer-vision, opencv, python

so i just learn image processing , and i read some website about detection contour then i found almost all website that ive been read use cv2.findcontour , ive read documentation of cv2.findcontour but i couldnt find how cv2.findcontour works, step by step, can anyone suggest me what should i read or any website that contain how cv2.findcontour work step by step? or any suggestion what should i learn firsr before i learn cv.findcontour? i already understand canny edge and blur image thank yoy

Comment: [Image processing - Contours](https://datacarpentry.org/image-processing/09-contours/)

Comment: I can only say wow. The link nathancy refering to is super cool. It explains very details in a very easy to understand way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `opencv` documentation for this function there is a link to a paper with an actual algorithm. Furthermore, there are examples (in section `Examples`), where this function is used.
Check it out: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

The link to the paper
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/de3/citelist.html#CITEREF_Suzuki85